# getting query params from url Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, routeparams

I want to grab id  from url

```
http://localhost:4200/courses/5a0eb3d7f6b50c2589c34e57
```

so in my app.module.ts I have such route

```
{path:'courses/:id', component:CourseComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
```

and in my course.component.ts I have the following code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {

  id: String;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.queryParams["id"];
    console.log(this.id)
  }

}
```

Actually in my developer console I can see following [image]
And if I try to console.log(params) I get following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a route param and you should be using the params property

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use rxjs.

```
this.route.params.pluck('id').subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

Preferable, since `.params` might be depracated soon:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => paramMap.get('id'));
```

Everything is in documentation... https://angular.io/guide/router#parammap-api